# Iterable implementation with an iterator with a mutable hasNext(), is this inherently flawed?

Tags: java, pagination, iterator

My immediate reaction to finding a mutable `hasNext()`, was that this could not possibly be correct, and would depend on external usage relying on what I imagine is a contract for java iterables (my limited search did not yield results, so perhaps there isn't one).

However, in this case, the internals is based on pagination. So the following pseudocode-ish explains the functionality:

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
   if (collection == null || index >= collection.size()) {
      collection = getCollectionContent(page++);
      index = 0;
      return collection.size() > 0;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Now, aside from the requirement to call `hasNext()` lest you receive a NPE on `next()`. It works when used in the typical loop:

```
while(foo.hasNext()) {
    useFooItem(foo.next());
}
```

And behaves properly in terms of iterating through all the elements in the paginated collection.

Now, I'm arguing that this is inherently flawed. `hasNext()` should never be mutable. However, it seems to solve the pagination iteration nicely, and I'm not able to make a very convincing argument.

Can you think of a normal use case where the above would be flawed?

Comment: Nit: `hasNext()` isn't mutable: you can't change `hasNext()` to something else. `hasNext()` *mutates* the object's state.

Comment: That probably depends on what `getCollectionContent()` is doing, i.e. would it be possible that the entire (non-paged) collection could change in between?

Comment: @AndyTurner: Isn't "a mutable method" in java something that would describe a method that mutates the state of the object? The lack of const-correctness in java makes the whole concept a bit weird in my C++ based experience. But, alas, let's agree that what you mean, is what I meant :)

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with mutating state in an implementation of `Iterator.hasNext()`. For instance, Guava's [`AbstractIterator`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.java#L132) has the `tryToComputeNext()` method, which may be called when you call `hasNext()`.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, it could. But for the sake if this reduced example, we can assume it won't change.

Comment: @swalog no such thing as a mutable method, in Java at least. You describe a class as mutable or immutable; not individual methods. It's a pretty nit-picky difference, I will admit.

Comment: If the collection can change in between calls to `getCollectionContent()` you could get effects like skipping elements or visiting elements multiple times etc. In fact each call to `hasNext()` and `next()` can suffer from that, hence the standard collections' iterators keep track of the modification cound and throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if it changes unexpectedly. If your iterator can do something similar it might be relatively safe to use but depending on what `getCollectionContent()` internally does that might be hard to achieve.

Comment: @AndyTurner: But... when talking about things, and using the English language. Could it not be used to describe what I mean to describe? There is no strict concept of mutability in Java as there is no const correctness. Any use of it for java is at best a poor mans version of it. So whenever people talk about mutability in java, I've come to find that they mean to say that the class is "strongly designed to disallow mutating the state", which does not encompass state of class members, unless they too follow that pattern, with turtles all the way down. In any case, separate discussion.

Comment: I find it hard to answer this without extra context about what collection exactly is but if that's only local to the Iterator then afaict this seems like a correct way of implementing hasNext. The method is still idempotent, multiple calls to it won't change anything unless the underlying collection has changed or the state of the Iterator has changed (by next() call for example).

Comment: @Thomas, @Alawoniak: `getCollectionContent()` gets elements from a database. No elements are removed, only added. Entries could be updated and modified, but that would be fine. Calls to `getCollectionContent()` are idempotent, as any calls to `size()` would not be affected by any allowed external changes.

Comment: Everything discussed in the comments has been educational, and I understand this all better. Thanks :)

Comment: So the query doesn't sort the elements?

Comment: @AndyTurner: I understand now what the objection was. I'd say that the following definition is ok: "A mutable method is a method that can mutate the instance's state".

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you have a very good point there. Entries are in fact ordered by something that could very well change.